# Installing Go on Ubuntu - "The program 'go' is currently not installed"

Tags: software-installation

This should be a simple thing.

I followed the instruction on "http://golang.org/doc/install" to install "Go" on Ubuntu.

1. Downloaded it
2. Unzipped it to "usr/local"
3. Added the path in "/etc/profile" (export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin)

But when I type in "go" it says "The program 'go' is currently not installed".

What should I do?

Comment: Add the path to your .profile in your home...

Comment: doesn't "/etc/profie" apply a system-wide variable so I don't have to add in ".profile"? What if another user wants to run "go"?

Comment: after adding the path source the etc/profile file.

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful?

Comment: Just adding to /etc/profile does not make it active in your current shell.  You need a new login shell.

Answer (score 5):

```
gedit /etc/profile
```

Add the below line,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Then source the /etc/profile,

```
source /etc/profile
```

Logout and login back.

Comment: This is strange, I did "source /etc/profile" and it worked. Then I logged out and logged back in and it now says the same error "go is not installed". When I "source" again, it works.

Comment: Also, when I do "source" it works under my user name, but if I change to "root", I get "go is not installed" error again. ???

Comment: after sourcing the profile file,restart your pc.

Comment: That's not working either.

Comment: to make it system-wide add the path to /etc/environment see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables

Comment: ok I added that, then I "sourced" it and it worked. But when I log out and log back in, it doesn't work.

Comment: did you add the path in /etc/environment file?

Comment: for root put the path inside `/root/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, for system-wide installation:

```bash
echo 'PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/usr/local/go/bin' | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
```

Logout then back in.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install go 1.0.3 on ubuntu is to do

```
sudo apt-get install golang-stable
```

To install version 1.1.1 do this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties  # 12.04
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:duh/golang
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install golang
```

Source: [How to install current version of go on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480044/how-to-install-the-current-version-of-go-in-ubuntu)

Comment: It seems like the PPA is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

What fixed it for me was sourcing it in my .bashrc

You can do this yourself by doing:

`nano ~/.bashrc`

Then add the line at the top of the file.

`source /etc/profile`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to write then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

Close than reopen your terminal and type `go` and you should see a list of commands pop up.

I'm still new to linux and I'm sure there's a better way, but that's whats worked to far for me

Answer (score 0):

After having a bit of trouble with this myself, and taking time to read a bit from [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables), I believe the best solution for most users is to do:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

This opens a file you can use to save persistent variables for your user session (it won't be persistent system-wide, but if you're the only user, or will be the only one using Go, it's ideal). So add this at the bottom:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Saving the file will not affect the system immediately; you must fully log out of your Ubuntu session (via the top-right gear) and log back in. Open a terminal window and check if it worked by entering:

```
go help
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `/etc/profile`, run this instead:

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" >> .bashrc
```

And then source the file:

```
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

You can find details here: https://www.begueradj.com/installing-golang-on-ubuntu.html